# Error messaging when enabling jQuery 1.4.2 on project build path

Tags: jquery, aptana

I'm trying to configure my project with auto-completion for jQuery 1.4.2 in Aptana 3.  I've installed the jQuery bundle, restarted Eclipse and given my project a "Web" nature.  I see the option to enable jQuery 1.4.2 and 1.6.2 in the project.  However when I check the box and click Ok, it is throwing an error in the logs and auto-completion isn't working.  The error message that shows in the Eclipse log is:

Plugin: com.aptana.parsing
Message:  (Build 3.2.2.1343263605) [ERROR]  Invalid return type:

Can someone suggest what I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  It seems like those messages are not really part of the problem.  The problem was that I was using the wrong editor.  I needed to right-click on the Javascript file, select Open With...  The option that was the default was Javascript Editor.  I needed to select Javascript Source Editor which is probably the editor that is associated with Aptana.  Once I did that, then the type-ahead work correctly.

Hope this helps someone else.